# How can I delete a dataframe column by name if the name is a variable in a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a loop I created to iterate through the column names and delete them in some cases. I'm trying this code below but it won't work. I'm unable to use call the dataframe column based on a variable name. It's expecting the actual name. Is there any way around this?

```
for name, values in (df.iteritems())
     .....
     .....
     del df[name]
```

Comment: Plz review your code and make it clear so we can understand whta were you tring to do

Comment: " I'm unable to use call the dataframe column based on a variable name. It's expecting the actual name." That doesn't make any sense. What exactly is the error you are getting?  One reason the code you have may not work is because you are removing from the data structure as you iterate over it. I'm not sure how `.iteritems` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Use drop function

```
list =['list of columns']

for col in list:
    df.drop(col,axis=1,inplace=True)
```